# Ubuntu 22.04 hangs on boot, log shows the system is still running, cannot find cause

Tags: boot, 22.04

Running Ubuntu 22.04 on an HP HP ProBook 450. often on startup, the system will hand immediately after showing the fsck output. A non blinking cursor is shown and the system is not responsive, Only a hard reboot clears this. An error message is shown - different ones at different times.

On reviewing syslogs, however, it appears that the system goes on working. i have listed below some of the messages I see at hang.

```
# journalctl --since today

kernel: tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
===
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
===
kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
===
[drm:nv_drm_load [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to allocate NvKmsKapiDevice
[drm:nv_drm_probe_devices [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to register device
BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000040
#PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
#PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
--
Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
--
thermald[1964]: Unsupported condition 9 (Aggregate_power_percentage)
thermald[1964]: Unsupported condition 9 (Aggregate_power_percentage)
thermald[1964]: Unsupported conditions are present
thermald[1964]: Polling mode is enabled: 4
kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
-- 
kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
--
gdm-launch-environment][3113]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Most of these issues seem unlikely to hang the system, and as I said, the logs record ongoing activity even after I see no response from the console.

Increasingly, I am suspecting that the system is failing to start the windowing system, as I am seeing logs entries such as the following

```
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (EE)
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: Fatal server error:
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (EE) no screens found(EE)
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (EE)
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]:          at http://wiki.x.org
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]:  for help.
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
Apr 17 06:41:23 tigger /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3137]: (EE)
```

Nowadays a power up is taking 4 to 5 startups to get to a successful boot, which sometimes is through recovery-mode and the boot-repair utility.

Any advise on how to troubleshoot and fix this would be appreciated.

This happens while running with both the Nvidia drivers and nouveau drivers

Comment: Did you check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for details as recommended? Also, try to remove all `.conf` files related to Xorg and check if something change.

Comment: @Serg I have temporarily installed the nouveau drivers to isolate the problem to the nvidia drivers. If this fixes it I will know its the nvida drivers and will user your recommendations. There are a few issues reported on the Xorg.0.log file. The issue is pointing towards the x-server not being able to start.

Comment: Using `nouveau` or inappropriate nvidia driver could be a problem with some older nvidia chips on 22.04. Try to boot with Ubuntu Live USB and if it boots then view Xorg log for details. Also you may expect problems with `nouveau` when nvidia drivers are uninstalled correctly.